# How to show a multiple fields of documents in Firestore in one row of LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm new to Firestore.
I need to show two of the values of the fields, "category" and "title" [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YcPK.png), of documents in Firestore in one row of LazyColumn like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpDF1.png).
I tried some codes as below but they are shown like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcQK6.png).
Is it possible?

My code of MainActivity

```
var t = mutableListOf<String>()
    db.collection("posts")
        .get()
        
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                val category = document.data["category"].toString()
                val title = document.data["title"].toString()
                t.add(category)
                t.add(title)
                Log.d("black", "${document.id} => ${category}")
                Log.d("red", "${document.id} => ${title}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("gray", "Error getting documents.", exception)
        }
```

My code of View

```
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Beige),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp)
        ) {

            items(posts) { post ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()

                        .selectable(
                            selected = true,
                            onClick = { navController.navigate("PostContent") }
                        )
                        .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                ) {

                    Text(
                        text = "$post/category\n$post/title",
                        color = Brown,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(40.dp)
                    )
                }
```

Thank you.

Comment: "they are not shown correctly" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly isn't shown correctly? Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) can help.

Comment: Thank you. I need to show like this. "place about a(in one row)" and "food about b(in one row)". But they are shown as Pitcture 2.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I've just posted what I need to creat as Picture 1. I hope it helps. I'm a beginner of programming. Thank you very much for being patient with me, Alex.

Comment: Where do you get the `posts` variable from? How do you define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad implementation of the storing mechanism.

In the class where you are calling the database, add this line of code

```
data class Post(category: String, title: String)
```

Then, update the `t` variable like so

`var t = mutableStateListOf<Post>()`

Then, update the storing mechanism

```
db.collection("posts")
        .get()
        
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                val category = document.data["category"].toString()
                val title = document.data["title"].toString()
                t.add(Post(category, title))
                Log.d("black", "${document.id} => ${category}")
                Log.d("red", "${document.id} => ${title}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("gray", "Error getting documents.", exception)
        }
```

Now, I assume it is the same `t` variable you are somehow accessing in your `LazyColumn` as `posts`, so update that code like this

```
LazyColumn {

  items(posts) { post ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()

                        .selectable(
                            selected = true,
                            onClick = { navController.navigate("PostContent") }
                        )
                        .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                ) {

                    Text(
                        text = "${post.category}\n${post.title}",
                        color = Brown,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(40.dp)
                    )
                }
```

All done, modify the design however you like, the logic is good like this.